# Result of API Request to global variable?

Tags: variables, globals

I have an API Request for weather and the account of this weather stuff has a limitation of requests per minute. In my theme I have the weather information twice on the same page. So if I would make a function of the request it would fire twice. I thought about a global variable, where I could save the request once and grap this variable where ever I want.

Is this a good idea? I read something about, that global variables aren't a good choice!? Is there an other solution?

Comment: This would be a good use case for a transient: https://developer.wordpress.org/apis/handbook/transients/

Comment: thanks! this is nice. After reading about the transient I realized that "caching" might be something here. So after 1 sec of searching I found https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_cache_set/ 
But what's the difference between set_transient() and wp_cache_set() ?

Comment: @vriic transients are persistent (they're saved in the database as options), but object cache is not persistent by default - [more details here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_object_cache/#more-information).